# Rails scopes - undefined methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a model called "event" that has a scope named "upcoming" wich returns events that are dated in the future. In the rails console, whenever I type

```
Event.upcoming
```

It returns the subset of events successfully.
However if I type:

```
@events = Event.all
@events.upcoming
```

I get an undefined method 'upcoming' error. Are scopes only working on the class and not on instantiated variables?
Thanks in advance.
Yohann

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you call `.all`, `@events` is no longer an `ActiveRelation`, hence you cannot call a scope on it.

So, `Event.where(SOME CONDITIONS).order(ORDERING).upcoming.limit(X)` would still work, but `Event.where(SOME CONDITIONS).order(ORDERING).all.upcoming.limit(X)` would not work.

Comment: excellent! That solved my problems, thank you! Also just to append to what you said. any methods such as Event.find_all_xxx() break the ActiveRelation, hence scope won't work

Answer (score 12):

You can use `scoped` instead of `all` to get an active relation object that will allow you to chain scopes on the variable after it's been set:

```
@events = Event.scoped
@events.upcoming
```

Comment: great help, thx Beerlington. I had to give the "correct" answer mark to @zsquare though because he has the explanation on why it is happening. Thx again!