# Rails 5 - exclude specific instances from edit path on parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, associations, nested-attributes

I have models in my Rails 5 app for User, Proposal and Potential.

Users create Proposals which they themselves and others can then create comments on.

The associations between models are:

User

```
  has_many :proposals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :potentials
```

Proposal

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :potentials, inverse_of: :proposal
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :potentials, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Potential

```
belongs_to :proposal, inverse_of: :potentials
  belongs_to :user
```

In my routes file, I have two resources for potentials. I'm not sure if I've gone off piste with this bit- I cant find an example of how to do this otherwise. I have both:

```
resources :potentials
```

as well as:

```
resources :proposals do

    resources :potentials
```

The reason I have done this is so that when the user is creating a proposal, they can use a nested fields form to add potential attributes. When another user sees that proposal, they get a new form to add a :potential set of attributes (they don't do it via the proposal form).

In my potentials view folder, I have views for new which renders form for as well as potential_fields_for which is incorporated in my proposals form (only the proposal creator can use the nested fields).

The new/render form has:

```
<%= simple_form_for [ @proposal, @potential ] do |f| %>
f
```

The proposal form has:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :potentials do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
          <%= render 'potentials/potential_fields', f: f %>

      <% end %>


      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add another novel aspect', f, :potentials, partial: 'potentials/potential_fields' %>
      </div>
```

In my proposals controller, I'm trying to find a way to exclude 3rd party created :potentials from the fields displayed in the proposal form.

```
def edit
    @proposal.potentials_build unless @proposal.potentials || @proposal.potential.user_id != current_user.id
```

I don't want the proposal creator to be able to edit those fields from the proposal form but even if I don't touch them, the user id on the 3rd party potential gets updated to the proposal creator id when I update the proposal form (without updating those specific 3rd party potential attributes).

I tried to change the edit action in the proposals controller be excluding potentials created by a user that is not the current user id. Only the proposal creator can edit the proposal, so I expect that this will exclude instances of proposal.potential that have a user id other than the proposal.user_id.

That doesnt work.

Is there a way that I can limit the proposal#edit action to only those potential instances that are not created by the proposal creator?

**TARYN'S SUGGESTION**

I tried to adopt Taryn's thoughts about this.

In my proposal.rb, I made 2 scopes:

```
  scope :owner_potentials, ->{ where(user_id: potential.user_id ) }
    scope :third_party_potentials, ->{ where(user_id: != potential.user_id) }
```

I am not confident that this is the correct way to write a scope. Although I cant find a reference to how to write them, on previous occasions when I have tried to learn how to compose them, I have received advice to set them out in this format:

```
scope :owner_potentials, ->(user){ where(user_id: potential.user_id ) }
        scope :third_party_potentials, ->(user){ where(user_id: != potential.user_id) }
```

I tried this way as well, but I get the same error as I do if I don't include "(user)". I don't understand what that inclusion does or should do.

In my proposal controller, edit action, I have then tried each of the following:

```
# @proposal.potentials_build unless @proposal.potentials || @proposal.potential.user_id != current_user.id
        # @proposal.owner_potentials.build unless @proposal.owner_potentials
        #@potentials = @proposal.owner_potentials || @proposal.owner_potentials.build
```

The first one was my original attempt. It didnt work and prompted me to write this post.

The second one is the way I think it should be written.

The third is just incorporating Taryn's idea directly to see if that's how it should be written (although I think that was more of general way of describing what to do).

None of these work. In the case of the 2nd version of this attempt, I get an error that says:

```
NoMethodError at /proposals/17/edit
undefined method `owner_potentials' for #<Proposal:0x007f84f6ca1700>
```

I think the reason why this isnt working is that the scope is run on the class as a table, not the specific instance to be edited. I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413058/rails-scopes-undefined-methods) explains that.

Proposals have many potentials, so the idea is to check all of the potentials belonging to the specific proposal to see whether any of those potentials have the user id that is the same as the user id on the proposal instance.  How can I do that?

I cant write:

```
Proposal.owner_potentials.build unless Proposal.owner_potentials
```

in the proposal controller edit action because the set_proposal method is picking out the correct proposal for edit to apply on.

Can I use a scope in a controller edit action where there is a has_many relationship that is being tested by the scope?

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

My next thought is to try to define the scopes in the Potential model so that the scope can run on the class.

I tried:

```
scope :owner_potentials, ->{ where('user_id == potential.proposal.user_id' ) }
  scope :third_party_potentials, ->{ where('user_id != potential.proposal.user_id') }
```

I spent hours on codementor trying to learn scopes and my takeaway from that session is the syntax i used above is incorrect - but the way I was shown to write them (which is at the top of the post, gives an error with the undefined variable). I don't know how to figure out how to learn to write a scope.

Anyway-  next I tried changing the edit action in my Proposal controller to:

```
@proposal.potentials.owner_potentials.build unless @proposal.potentials.owner_potentials
```

Now, I get no errors when I save this and try it, but when I try to edit the proposal, I can still edit potentials that have been created by third parties. I don't understand whether Im not writing the scope effectively, or if this solution isnt going to work for another reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider adding a custom scoped association eg `owners_potentials`/`third_party_potentials` that limits potentials to those created by the owner/ by somebody other than the owner. You can then use these scopes whenever you need them.

eg

```
has_many :potentials, inverse_of: :proposal
has_many :owner_potentials, ->{ where("potentials.user_id = proposals.creator_id") }
has_many :third_party_potentials, ->{ where("potentials.user_id != proposals.creator_id") }
```

Then you could do something like:

```
def edit
  @potentials = @proposal.owner_potentials || @proposal.owner_potentials.build
```

Then in the form, be specific about using the one you've specified:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for @potentials do |f| %>
```

Note: code has not been tested or sanity-checked, it's here to give an idea of the kind of thing you can do - getting it to actually work is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Taryn.

Comment: Are you sure I can use a scope in the controller?

Comment: You define your scope in the model... you can use a scope anywhere that you have a model...

Comment: It doesnt work in the edit action because the edit action has a specific instance of the proposal. I'm trying to find a way to scope all the child 'potentials' that belong to that specific 'proposal'.

Comment: Yes... which is what the code in my example does... it chooses all the potentials that belong to the given proposal... then scopes them to only show the ones created by the owner of the proposal (or not).

Comment: Is your example an example I would include in the proposals controller? I cant get that to work.

Comment: The "def edit" part would go in the controller - the rest goes in the model or in the view. You may need to bug-fix my code. This is normal for Stack overflow answers. If you are getting an actual error message, please share it here if you need help figuring out why it isn't working. First up - add the model code, then test it returns what you actually want in the rails console - then move on to the controller... then the view. It's not a complete solution - this is an idea on how to use scopes to solve your problem... you will need to make it work in your particular situation.

Comment: The first attempt I set out above is my attempt at taking your suggestion and adding it to my code. My second attempt is set out under the heading "next attempt" above. I cant figure out how to apply a scope to the children of the specific instance on the proposal resource. I've asked a 2nd question to try to make sense of this concept:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772669/rails-5-using-a-scope-in-an-edit-action-to-find-relevant-children-of-a-specifi

Comment: `@proposal.potentials.owner_potentials` this is the bug... you don't need to type `potentials` and then also `owner_potentials` - just use `@proposal.owner_potentials` like in my example. These are scoped-associations defined on the `Proposal` model... not "true" scopes on the potentials model. Note the use of `has_many` not `scope` :)

Comment: oh - ok, thanks. I was trying to write a scope. I'll try again in the has_many association.

Comment: There may still be bugs... if so I apologise... it's all untested.  let me know how it goes and I'll try to help :)